# Refresh settings screen / update SettingsItem on config change

Tags: python, kivy

I have some settings panels created though json files. If the user changes a certain setting I use on_config_change to evaluate what the user has done. Now comes the tricky part:
Depending on the users choice I need to update other settings. The problem is, that I can write stuff to the config and the next time the settings are opened the new config is read, but I really can't figure out any way to "refresh" the settings screen and immediately display the updates, that I've done to the config.

Here's a small snipped from my on_config_change:

```
def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
    if section == 'my_section':
        if key == 'var1':
            if value > var2:
                # TODO: find a way to refresh the settings screen to reflect the change below
                self.config.set(section, key, var2)
                self.config.write()
                # self.settingsObj.canvas.ask_update()  # not working
                # self.settingsObj.do_layout()          # not working
```

I tried canvas.ask_update() and do_layout() to update the settings screen, but it didn't work.
I assume, that the value is an ObjectProperty and I can somehow access them to reflect changes instantly, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Btw: the goal is to limit the range of the value, that the user is entering.

I hope you can help me out! 
Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Cheers,
Claus